# Can lambda expressions be used on dynamic list to get results

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, json.net

I have following code:

```
dynamic jsonData = JObject.Parse(data);
var names= new List<dynamic>();
names= jsonData.Properties().Select(p => p.first_name).ToList();
```

I am unable to make this work as keep on getting error cannot use lambda. Is there a way to get this result? Or should I not use dynamic here?

Json string:

```
{"items":[{"id":404,"name":"Ken":{"id":215,"neighbourhood":"Mississauga"}]
    ,{"id":407,"name":"John":{"id":215,"neighbourhood":"Toronto"}]
    ,...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `dynamic`, I'd advise you not to use it, there's no point.

It appears you have an object with an `items` property which is an array of objects, and you're trying to grab the `name` of those objects.  Just do this:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(data);
var names = obj["items"]
    .Select(item => (string)item["name"])
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried doing this but getting following error: Additional information: Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "name". Int32 array index expected.

Comment: Well given what you've provided as an example, that would be impossible. The code I've shown makes no reference to an array or `"name"` property. you'll need to provide more information.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks! Just putting it out here may be will help someone else:  var names = obj.Descendants()
                    .OfType<JProperty>()
                    .Where(p => p.Name == "name")
                    .ToList();

Comment: Hmm, your code doesn't reflect your json at all (which is not valid either). But that could be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like so

```
... ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)jsonData.Properties()).Select( ...
```